# Deleted products are showing in while exporting products

Tags: magento-1.8, csv, export, inventory, importexport

I am exporting products using Dataflow profile. The exported inventory csv file contains the deleted products also.But in Manage product option,no deleted products appear. I have tried exporting after clearing cache and reindexing, but no use. Still the products exported with deleted products. How to export active products only ?

Comment: please trancate table dataflow_batch_export

Comment: We have checked the "dataflow_batch_export". There is no record.

Comment: Hi anybody help for this

Comment: Are you sure the products are not in the `catalog_product_entity` table? In some cases the products can be in there but not appear in the manage products section.

Comment: Same issue here. I wonder why it wasn't deleted. It doesnt show in the manage products section anymore but when you export it, the deleted product is in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer but I figured it out today. You have enable flat catalog in your M1 store.

The exported csv via System > Export, exports the in the catalog_product_entity. Not in the flat catalog.

If you want to delete the product without accessing the database directly, you need to disable flat catalog first, then delete the sku in Manage Products. Then export is via CSV. It will be gone.